# OneDrive CORS preflight fails when downloading file with Range header included

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

Currently, I am building a javascript app that provides OneDrive filesystem support for chromeOS. Unfortunately, I encounter an issue when downloading a file via the OneDrive API due to preflights failing.

Deeply buried in the [Microsoft API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/working-with-cors?view=odsp-graph-online#downloading-onedrive-files-in-javascript-apps) there is a mention of a workaround for CORS request for javascript apps, because preflights will fail. In order to circumvent a 302 redirect, a file download has to be executed in two steps: first get the download url, then download the file via that url. This works fine as a simple `GET` request doesn't require a preflight check.

Back to the filesystem. According to the [chrome.fileSystemProvider API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystemProvider#event-onReadFileRequested):

> The results must be returned in chunks by calling successCallback several times.

This can be achieved by using the `Range` header on the `GET` request to the download-url, which actually is supported by OneDrive API using [partial range downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#partial-range-downloads). However, now the request isn't simple anymore and therefore requires a preflight check, which ultimately fails.

So basically, the workaround failed because the problem the workaround tried to work around is still present in the workaround.

How can I overcome this problem? I obviously don't want to funnel the request through a proxy because of bandwidth and privacy issues. Can I perhaps simulate the `Range` header by downloading the entire file first and then serving it in byte-size chunks to the `fileSystemProvider`? 
I came across a [question asked almost 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068647/onedrive-cors-download-in-javascript) with a very similar issue, but unfortunately it didn't get me any further.

Comment: Can you confirm what OneDrive endpoint you're hitting (Business or Personal)?

Comment: I write for OneDrive for business, so the downloadUrl I retrieve from the api points to a file on a sharepoint source (still on office365 though).

Comment: It does seem like there isn't a valid work around for this scenario - we'll need to make sure `download.aspx` supports `OPTIONS` in order to get the scenario working.